# Send User ID from google tag manager to GA4 Issue

Tags: javascript, next.js, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4, userid

I am working on a next project, and from the `\_app.tsx` file, I am pushing this dummy data to the dataLayer of google tag manager

```
<Script id="gtm" strategy="beforeInteractive"> {
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || \[\];
window.dataLayer.push({event: 'test', 'userId': 'abc098'});
}</Script>
```

The objective I am trying to attain is that when I pass this userId to dataLayer in google tag manager; I want to be able to view this under Google Analytics -> Explore -> User Explorer Section

> In google tag  manager, I have done the following steps:

- Created a variable with the name `'userId'` (just as in my `dataLayer`)
- Then in my GA4 tag as you can see in the image I have attached below, under fields to set, I have added a field for :

1. `user_id` along with the variable I created
2. setting `debug_mode` with value 'true'
3. Under Property Name: I have added `user_id_dimension` with the `userId` variable
   [GA4 Tag Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1CkXo.png)

- Under triggers, I have created a custom event with the name 'test', referenced under my GA4 tag [Trigger Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5SvhO.png)

> In google analytics:

- For web data streams - I have enhanced measurement on
- Also created a custom definition for userId with `user_id_dimension` as created under property in gtm

When I preview my website on GTM; I am able to see that my test event is being pushed to `dataLayer` along with the `userId`, and my GA4 tag is also being fired.
But on Google Analytics, I am not able to see the `userId` in events or in the User Explorer section
I also have all my changes submitted on GTM.

Answer (score 0):

In your current setup, you're trying to pass the `user_id` as an event parameter, but what you need to do is pass it as a user property.

In GA4, user properties are attributes you define to describe segments of your user base, such as language preference or geographic location. Analytics automatically logs some user properties; you don't need to add any code to enable them. If you need to collect additional data, you can set up to 25 different Analytics user properties in your project.

In this case, you need to set the `user_id` as a user property so that it appears in the User Explorer section.

In GTM, instead of putting `user_id` under "Event Parameters", you should put it under "User Properties".

Here's how to do it:

1. In GTM, open your GA4 Configuration Tag.
2. In the tag configuration, scroll down to the "Event Parameters". Remove the `user_id` field from this section.
3. Further down, you'll find the "User Properties" section. Here, add a new row.
4. In the "Parameter" column, enter `user_id`. This is the reserved parameter name in GA4 for the user ID.
5. In the "Value" column, select your `userId` variable.
6. Save your changes.

Now, your `userId` should be passed to GA4 as a user property, and it should appear in the User Explorer section.

Remember to test your changes in GTM's preview mode and verify in the GA4 real-time report before publishing the changes. Also, user properties might take up to 24 hours to populate in the User Explorer section in GA4.

Comment: Thanks for taking time out to help me fix this, I have added user_id in my user property section with the variable userId, and here is my dataLayer script from which I am passing userId: <script async>
          {`
            window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || []; 
            window.dataLayer.push({event: 'test', 'userId': '${user_id_hash}'});
          `}
        </script> So now after 24 hours, this userid that I am passing here, it should get showed in user explorer report right

Comment: Also, under my Realtime Report, in users by user property, I dont have any data showing up, so how can I check if all is okay, or there is some issue